# Jquery Cropbox is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am Trying to crop image using jquery cropbox . Ref url : [Cropbox](https://github.com/acornejo/jquery-cropbox)
Everythhing is working fine but i m not able to drag the images

```
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

 <script src="http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/jquery.cropbox.js"></script>
   <link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/jquery.cropbox.css">
     <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#cropimage').cropbox({
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    }).on('cropbox', function(e, data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
</script>
 <img id="cropimage" alt="" src="http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/img.jpg" />
<div id="results">
 <b>X</b>: <span class="cropX"></span>
 <b>Y</b>: <span class="cropY"></span>
 <b>W</b>: <span class="cropW"></span>
 <b>H</b>: <span class="cropH"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: _"not able to drag the images"_ ? `cropbox` will make `crop-box` drag-able  right ?

Comment: yup . for help read this artical : https://github.com/acornejo/jquery-cropbox

Comment: So what is the question ? Do share a fiddle to make us execute this...

Comment: no . just create a html file && copy and past the code  .  you will  understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

> **Bug** regarding latest version of chrome and version of `hammer.js` are listed [*here*](https://github.com/acornejo/jquery-cropbox/issues)

Use the versions of libraries mentioned in example provided in documentation.

```js
$('.cropimage').cropbox({
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  showControls: 'auto'
}).on('cropbox', function(event, results, img) {
  console.log(results);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/1.0.5/hammer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.6/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

<script src="http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/jquery.cropbox.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/jquery.cropbox.css">
<img class="cropimage" alt="" src="http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/img.jpg" />
<div class="results">
  <b>X</b>: <span class="cropX"></span>  <b>Y</b>: <span class="cropY"></span>
  <b>W</b>: <span class="cropW"></span>  <b>H</b>: <span class="cropH"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: seriusly . ?? WTF . I have waste my time because of this reason :(

Comment: @codeBloger, I did spend few minutes as well but thought about going through issues section as I have faced such things many times...